# If $A$ and $B$ are matrices of the same rank, can $A$ transformed into $B$ by row and column operations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I think the answer is correct by RREF and transposition. But i don't know how to prove that.

Comment: Consider a change of basis for the column space of $A$ and column space of $B$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Since $A$ and $B$ have the same rank, when we reduce them to RREF using row operations (which correspond to left-multiplication by elementary matrices) they will end up having the same number of leading $1$’s. Then we can use column operations (which correspond to right-multiplication by elementary matrices) to delete entries above and below each leading $1$, and then rearrange the columns so that the two matrices match up and are identical; call this final reduced matrix $C$.

So we have $PAQ = C = P’BQ’$, where $P, Q, P’, Q’$ are compositions of elementary matrices. Since the inverse of elementary matrices are also elementary matrices, $(P')^{-1}$ and $(Q')^{-1}$ are also compositions of elementary matrices.

So $B = (P')^{-1}PAQ(Q')^{-1}$, showing that $B$ can be changed to $A$ by row and column operations.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

If $A$ and $B$ have the same rank, you can write
$$
AQ=PB
$$
where $P, Q$ are invertible matrix (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800107/prove-a-and-b-are-equivalent-if-and-only-if-textranka-textrankb)). So the answer is yes (using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899761/why-is-a-matrix-invertible-if-it-can-be-written-as-the-product-of-elementary-mat)).